# How can I create a non-login user?

Tags: linux, user-accounts

I'd like to create a user and a group both called `subversion` on a RHEL 5 system. I looked at the man page for `useradd` and I guess the command would be just be...

```
useradd subversion
```

However, not sure how to avoid creating a home dir. Also, I don't want it to be a user that can log in to the system.

The main purpose is just to provide an owner for a SVN repository.

Comment: Have you really looked at man page of useradd and didn't find -M (do not create HOME directory)?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can use the `-M` switch (make sure it's a capital) to ensure no home directory will be created:

```
useradd -M subversion
```

then lock the account to prevent logging in:

```
usermod -L subversion
```

Comment: This isn't a particularly strong answer, the user created by this means still has a shell. And you did not even warn the OP that this was the case. Retrospectively that would be `usermod -s /bin/false subversion`, or with `--shell /bin/false` to `useradd`

Comment: @beak the account is locked, having a shell is a moot point.

Comment: except that one can still `su` to a locked account, that's not true with an account with no shell. A small point, but with server management it doesn't hurt to be thorough

Comment: @beak actually only the root user would be able to su to the locked account, but why bother if the person has gained root access already? And setting the shell doesn't do much when a user can run `su -s /bin/bash username` and bypass that.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to have the discussion, you are of course correct; but it pains me to see non-login users with shells defined, it strikes me as lazy, and incase someone is unfamiliar with the system, it's nice that they can't accidentally do something unintended; hackers are a different breed, if they already got a shell on the machine, I think it's basically game over

Comment: These comments covered exactly the things I was hoping to learn, thanks @Beaks && John T

Comment: I had a problem with `useradd -M` hanging, but this worked fine: `adduser --no-create-home --disabled-login USERNAME`

Comment: I was curious about this conversation and did some man page reading.  I successfully unlocked an account by changing the password (using _root_ of course).  The point is however that if one is able to alter the password, the -L lock can be avoided.  I think the shell thing is relevant if you want _backup_ .

Comment: All it takes is one bug in the shell and this is a recipe for disaster. useradd -s /bin/false username is highly preferable. (usermod would modify an existing user)

Comment: @LeeHambley I see a lot of criticism and discussion but I don't see a separate answer from you. It would be better for you to post the process that you consider to be correct.

Comment: useradd -M username assigns a home dir to the user without creating it. What you are looking for is a user that doesn't have a home.

Answer (score 301):

You can use the following command:

```
useradd -r subversion
```

For more info, check [manual pages](http://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd) with this command:

```
man useradd
```

You will find in this documentation the following flag that can be used for your purpose.

```
-r, --system                  create a system account
```

The `-r` flag will create a system user - one which does not have a password, a home dir and is unable to login.

Comment: this command will even create a group for the user called the same. So the "subversion" user will be in the "subversion" group.
Great for when you later want to do "sudo chown -R subversion:subversion /path/to/folder"

Comment: with -r alone we can still login though. we need -s /bin/false to disable the user shell.

Comment: @c4il But the only one that can login into them is root, right? I mean, they don't have a password, so I would expect only root to be able to log into them.

Comment: but we can assign them passwords anyways, I tried `passwd subversion`.

Answer (score 44):

Another solution to create a system user, using `adduser` :

```
adduser --system --no-create-home --group yourusername
```

You can remove `--group` if you don't need group yourusername, and `--no-create-home` if you do need a home for this user.

As mentionned by py4on in comments, on some systems one may need to use the `--disabled-login` option in order to, well, disable login for this user.  It seems to be the default behaviour under Debian, though.

Beware that the numeric ID of the user will be of a system account.  You can fix the uid using the `--uid` option, though.

Finally, note that on some systems (e.g. Fedora) `adduser` is a symlink to `useradd`, in which case this answer is not valid.

Comment: To address "I don't want it to be a user that can log in" add the flag `--disabled-login` as well (before `yourusername`)

Comment: @py4on : Though this option is documented in the manpage, it seems to be the default under Debian at least.

Answer (score 34):

The cleanest answer to the original question is to run the command:

```
adduser subversion --shell=/bin/false
```

And if you don't want the home directory either:

```
adduser subversion --shell=/bin/false --no-create-home
```

or, if you want an even more locked down system user (Normally this won't create a home directory - it has been reported that it will still create a home directory in linux mint as per comment below)

```
adduser subversion --system --group
```

All these commands will create a group with the same name as the user

Comment: On Mint the last command definitely creates a home dir: `Creating home directory '/home/nodejs' ...`

Comment: should I also add `L`

Answer (score 27):

The safest form of doing this would be to use `adduser` like so:

```
$ adduser -r -s /bin/nologin subversion
```

**NOTE:** Be sure to include `-s /sbin/nologin` to disable any login shell from being made available to the account.

#### Confirmation of setup

```
$ grep subversion /etc/passwd /etc/shadow
/etc/passwd:subversion:x:496:496::/home/subversion:/bin/nologin
/etc/shadow:subversion:!!:17232::::::
```

However there's no directory:

```
$ ll /home | grep subversion
$
```

Confirm that the account is otherwise usable:

```
$ sudo -u subversion whoami
subversion

$ sudo -u subversion date
Tue Mar  7 08:58:57 EST 2017
```

#### Removal

If you need to remove this account:

```
$ userdel subversion -r
userdel: subversion mail spool (/var/spool/mail/subversion) not found
userdel: subversion home directory (/home/subversion) not found
$
```

And confirm:

```
$ grep rtim-hc-user /etc/passwd /etc/shadow
$
```

Comment: adduser doesn't recognize the -r option. I think you meant useradd.

Comment: @felwithe no, every answer I write up I always test before posting. I checked and that switch shows on a CentOS 6.x system.

Comment: Here is a [pastebin of the result](https://pastebin.com/raw/2fcaYPkA). I'm on Ubuntu 16 LTS. I don't know what version of adduser is installed but I never imagined it would change much over time or system to system. I then tried it with a --system flag instead, which created a homedir for the user (I didn't want one). Finally I just did it with useradd instead of adduser and it worked as planned. So I just assumed that you'd mistyped it as adduser when it was supposed to be useradd.

Comment: @felwithe yeah I wasn't doubting you, just letting you know that I tried it 8-). I'm a mod on the Unix and Linux site and these cmds are notoriously different b/w distros. The OP mentions RHEL in the question hence why I answered it like so, but they didn't tag it as red hat specific, which is part of the confusion on this Q&A IMO.

Answer (score 7):

In Debian, you could create a system user (without home directory) and login shell:

```
useradd --system --shell=/usr/sbin/nologin <username>
```

If your `nologin` program is in `/sbin/nologin`, please change accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

On a CentOS 7 machine you can use the following commands:

- If the user does not exist:

  ```
  useradd testuser --shell=/sbin/nologin
  ```
- if you want to modify an existing user:

  ```
  usermod testuser --shell=/sbin/nologin
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Start by generating an encrypted password for the user with a maximum of 8 characters long by doing:

```
openssl passwd -crypt new_password_less_than_eight_chars_long
```

Then you do:

```
useradd -m -g groupname -G otherGroupsSeperatedByComma -p encryptedPassword username
```